# PHP mail() won't send when included in other PHP file with user input email

Tags: php, html, email

I am generating a page of information from a database. I need to send an email with the page content as a reminder. (example here takes input as message)
It takes in an email address and is supposed to send the details to that address.

```
<div class="container">
        <?php
            $name = $_GET['info'];

            if(isset($name)){

                $info = explode('|', $name);

                /*****************************************************
                        open conection to the mySQL database
                ******************************************************/
                                         ....
                /*****************************************************
                        Populate the page 
                ******************************************************/
                $sql="Select information from table";

                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    /*Title*/
                    echo '<h1>'.$row['post_title'].'</h1><hr>';

                    /*content*/
                    echo '<h2>Details: </h2><br>'.$row['post_content'].'<br>';

                    $content = $row['post_title'];

                    /*Reminder*/
                    echo '<div data-role="collapsible">
                        <h1>Send a reminder</h1>';
                        include("includes/email_reminder.php");             
                    echo'</div>';
                }


                /*****************************************************
                        Close connection
                ******************************************************/
                mysqli_close($con);

            } else {

                echo'Nothing selected. Go back <br> 
                <a href="#" data-rel="back"> <img src="img/icon/Back.png" style="height: 3em" > </a>';

            }
        ?>

    </div>
```

That creates a form at the bottom of the page to take in the email that needs that needs a reminder.
This is email_reminder.php:

```
<?php
function spamcheck($field)
{
    // Sanitize e-mail address
    $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    // Validate e-mail address
    if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
?>

<?php
    // display form if user has not clicked submit
    if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
?>    

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">

Your Email: <input type="text" name="to"><br>

Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>

Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback">

</form>

<?php 
    }
    else    // the user has submitted the form

    {
        // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
        if (isset($_POST["to"]))
        {
            // Check if "from" email address is valid
            $receivecheck = spamcheck($_POST["to"]);

            if ($receivecheck==FALSE)
            {
                echo "Invalid input";
            }

            else
            {
                $to = $_POST["to"]; //receiver

                $subject = $_POST["subject"];

                $message = $_POST["message"];

                // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
                $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

                // send mail
                mail("$to",$subject,$message,"From: myaddress@mail.com\n");

                echo "reminder has been sent";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I have used that form in isolation (just opened email_reminder.php on its own) and it sent emails correctly from whichever email address I used. It just doesn't send when included in the other script.

Answer (score 1):

`include(emai_reminder.php);` needs single quotes surrounding the file name (and email correctly spelled: `include('email_reminder.php');`

But, it looks like you need more help than just this. For example, there is no field `FROM` in your form, although you reference `$_POST["from"]`. You're running validation against that variable, which doesn't exist, which fails validation, which prevents the `else if` block from running, which prevents `mail()` from ever being called.

Comment: I have been working on it over the last day. I have it working when I just open the email_reminder.php on its own. It will send emails as I need them. However once it is included, it just says error loading page when submit is pressed. I will update the code with the near working code

Answer (score 0):

Several reasons why mailing to different user-defined addresses may not work:

1.) Check the result from the `mail()` call is `TRUE`, just to make sure the underlying `sendmail` (if you are on Linux) did not return an error.

2.) Add additional headers to prevent problems when delivering mails to foreign SMTP hosts, an example may be found on [PHP doc for mail()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#108368)

3.) In some cases (i.e. when using SMTP on Windows) using the [PEAR Mail package](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) may solve your problem. It also supports ASMTP and error trapping is much easier compared to the `mail()` function.